# Sequence of discontinuous functions converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subset. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued functions such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$. Let $D_n$ denote the set of discontinuities of each $f_n$ and $D$ denotes the set of discontinuities of $f$. Then, can we say that $|D| \leq |D_n|$?

The result seems to be true but unable to prove it.

Comment: May be, in a particular way. But, the above question is more generalized one. My question is basically related to the cardinality to their respective set of discontinuities.

Comment: You ask if we can say that $|D| \leq |D_n|$. The linked counterexample shows that we cannot.

Comment: For what $n$ are asking if $|D| \leq |D_n|$ holds?  It certainly need not hold for $n=1$.